# button with entry alignment with grid

Tags: tkinter

I'm learning tkinter and I'm having trouble using the pack and grid geometry manager. Using the grid I am not able to align two buttons with the entry, as shown in the image. Any instructions in this direction?

```
# Formulário cadastrar
style.configure("TFrame")
frm_principal = ttk.Frame(frm_save, style="TFrame")
frm_principal.pack()


lb_english = ttk.Label(frm_principal, text="English", width=15, anchor="e", padding=(10, 0))
lb_english.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
entry_english = ttk.Entry(frm_principal)
entry_english.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)


lb_portuguese = ttk.Label(frm_principal, text="Portuguese", width=15, anchor="e", padding=(10, 0))
lb_portuguese.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
entry_portuguese = ttk.Entry(frm_principal)
entry_portuguese.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)

frm2 = ttk.Frame(frm_save)
frm2.pack()
bt_save = ttk.Button(frm2, text="Save", command=cadastrar)
bt_save.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w", )
bt_cancelar = ttk.Button(frm2, text="Cancelar", command=limpar_entry)
bt_cancelar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="e")
```

[image]

Comment: The Labels/Entries and the Buttons do not share a parent; therefore their respective grid row/column numbers are completely unrelated to each other.  Put all of these widgets into a single container, either a Frame or the window itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to create `frm2` as a child of `frm_principal` and put it at `row=2` and `column=1`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
# Formulário cadastrar
style.configure("TFrame")
frm_principal = ttk.Frame(frm_save, style="TFrame")
frm_principal.pack()


lb_english = ttk.Label(frm_principal, text="English", width=15, anchor="e", padding=(10, 0))
lb_english.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
entry_english = ttk.Entry(frm_principal)
entry_english.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"


lb_portuguese = ttk.Label(frm_principal, text="Portuguese", width=15, anchor="e", padding=(10, 0))
lb_portuguese.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
entry_portuguese = ttk.Entry(frm_principal)
entry_portuguese.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"

frm2 = ttk.Frame(frm_principal) # use frm_principal as parent
frm2.grid(row=2, column=1)      # use grid() instead of pack()
bt_save = ttk.Button(frm2, text="Save", command=cadastrar)
bt_save.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
bt_cancelar = ttk.Button(frm2, text="Cancelar", command=limpar_entry)
bt_cancelar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="e")
```

Comment: Perfeito acw1668, agora está fazendo mais sentido pra mim. Muito obrigado